# Using a Cordova plugin with Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I've been working through this example:
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/cordova

I've run:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-qrscanner
npx cap sync
```

and I can see the plugin installed in my node_modules.

What I do not know how to do is call one of the functions on the cordova-plugin. I'm wondering if I need a packager like webpack?

I'm also confused as to how this works if the cordova plugin contains native swift (or other) code.

Comment: just use it as you used it with Cordova

Comment: I have never used cordova

Comment: Then just read the plugin docs

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remember you can install the native wrapper too.  It should work just the same as using it with Cordova.

```
npm install @ionic-native/qr-scanner
```

From:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-qrscanner
npm install @ionic-native/qr-scanner
```

To:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-qrscanner
npm install @ionic-native/qr-scanner
npx cap sync
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner

Comment: The link you shared says Capacitors is Not compatible with this plugin? Did you actually try this and it worked?

Comment: @Mehdi.  It's to long ago now I can't remember.  However I looked at a project I did to read QR codes and I used phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.  Hope that helps.