# Ionic Capacitor - how to play ringtone/alarm on Android device?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, alarm, capacitor

I would like to know if there is a way to play Android device ringtone/alarm using [Ionic Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/) (not [Cordova](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-ringtones))?

If it is possible, please provide me with a simple solution (include required npm packages and code).
If not, please tell me how to do it with a simple typescript - I do not want to do it with a Cordova.

Also, I do not want to use [Capacitor Local Notifications](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/local-Notifications). I want ringtone sound only.

Thank you for any help :))

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that link ? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-ringtones

You can install it using Capacitor.

- npm install cordova-plugin-native-ringtones
- npm install @ionic-native/native-ringtones
- ionic cap sync

Save some `.caf` file in your `assets` repository and do the following :

```
import { NativeRingtones } from '@ionic-native/native-ringtones/ngx';


constructor(private ringtones: NativeRingtones) { }

...
this.ringtones.getRingtone().then((ringtones) => { console.log(ringtones); });

this.ringtones.playRingtone('assets/ringtones/sound_1.caf');

this.ringtones.stopRingtone('assets/ringtones/sound_1.caf');
```

Comment: Well, that was just copying/pasting from this link, and I think it contains everything to do what he needs. But you're right, here an edit

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if you read my question carefully you will see that I don't want to use Cordova Native Ringtones - I even provided the very same link as you did. I want to do it using Capacitor only. I guess right now it is impossible and we need to wait for new version of it, or something. The answer is good, so I will leave it, but the question is still open.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716200/using-a-cordova-plugin-with-capacitor
It's the "capacitor" way to use cordova plugins

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787916/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-ionic-native-cordova-plugins-with-ionic-react

Comment: So I just tried this and it didn't work, the github repo of the plugin doesn't have much info either. The playRingtone promise never fulfills or even errors, as if the function is never called. Any ideas for doing this in 2021?