# What is the right way to use Ionic Native / Cordova Plugins with Ionic (React) & Capacitor?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

How can I use Ionic Native / Cordova Plugins with Ionic React (not Angular) using Capacitor instead of Cordova?

I want to make use of [Screen Orientation Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation) with Capacitor and Ionic React. This is because Cordova is not officially supported for Ionic React projects. [Know More](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/overview).

This is what I have tried.

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation'
.
.
.
.
useEffect(() => {
    ScreenOrientation.lock(ScreenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE)
}, [])
```

My package.json has the following **relevant** dependencies installed.

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.13.0",
"@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.13.0",
"cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2"
```

The application builds successfully, but still opens in Portrait mode on my Android device. If I try to display the following,

```
console.log(ScreenOrientation.type)
```

The app builds successfully, but the screen goes blank.

Capacitor's Native APIs work flawlessly with Ionic React. For example,

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core'
const { StatusBar } = Plugins
.
.
useEffect(() => {
    StatusBar.hide()
}, [])
```

Will hide the status bar on my Android device.

Is this the right approach for using Cordova Plugins with Capacitor in Ionic React? [Reference](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/using-cordova-plugins)

If yes, what am I doing wrong here? And if no, how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved! I was doing everything right, I had just forgotten to run `npx cap sync` after installing my Ionic Native Plugin.

So, the right way to use Cordova Plugins with Capacitor & Ionic (React) is

```
npm install @ionic-native/javascript-package-name
npm install cordova-plugin-name
npx cap sync
```